# Getting all input value of the loop and display it

Tags: java

I want to get all the input values from entered Sales amount but it only gives me the last value I input , and also to display all amount . thanks

This is the ouput looks like.

> Please enter the number of salespeople to be processed: 3
>
> Enter and ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: 1 150
>
> Enter and ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: 2 250
>
> Enter and ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: 3 350
>
> ```
>           Weekly Sales by Salesperson 0         1          2  .
> ```
>
> the 3 amount of sales should be displayed here.
>
> Total Sales: 1800

```
{
    int i = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of salespeople to be processed: ");
    howmany = input.nextInt();

     int[] array = new int[howmany];


    while ( i <= array.length - 1  )

    {
        System.out.print("Enter and ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: ");        
        numberOfSales = input.nextInt();
        Salesmoney = input.nextInt();
        addwan += Salesmoney;
        i++;
    }

    HAHA();

    for (int j = 0; j < i ; j++)
    {

        System.out.print( + j + "     ");

        addwan += Salesmoney;

        System.out.print(Salesmoney + "     ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nTotal Sales: " + addwan + " ");

    }   

public static void HAHA()
{

    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tWeekly Sales by Salesperson");

}

}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @nafas it should out put like this ,
 0      1     2 .
150 250 350
total sales: 1800
 but it only display my last input and does not display all the amount.

Comment: plz explain the 1800 im confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

roughly scetched, I guess you would want to have smthg like this:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the number of salespeople to be processed: ");
howmany = input.nextInt();

int[][] array = new int[2][howmany];//2D array to store the amount, and worth of the item


for (int i=0; i<howmany;i++  )
{
    System.out.print("Enter and ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: ");        
    array[0][i] = input.nextInt();
    array[1][i] = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tWeekly Sales by Salesperson");
int addwan=0;
for (int j = 0; j < howmany ; j++)
{

    System.out.println( "Eintrag: "+j+" number of sales: "+array[0][j]+" itemworth: "+array[1][j]);
    addwan+=array[0][j]*array[1][j];
}

System.out.println("\nTotal Sales: " + addwan + " ");
```

Guessed i right that your ID-number has to be multiplied with the amount? because i coundt figure out the 1800 sales... even thou they are 1700...

Comment: haha done . ah btw is there any chance to compare an arraylist value to a int value ? like for example int[] arraylist = {1 , 2 }; int Val = 2; even if it's a only one value it can still be considered as true because arraylist has a value of 2 .

Comment: you have to create a loop, and check every item in the array, but if you use a ArrayList you can check it with the arraylist.contains(Val). The green check is not done yet :)

Comment: haha sorry . now it is really done . btw if i use arraylist do i still need to use a loop ? and is it ok to use an integer ? to compare it to the arraylist?

Comment: with an ArrayList you dont need a loop, just use .contains

Comment: i think contains is just for string right ? is there any for integer values ? for the arraylist ? being compare to another int value

Comment: The String class got it as well, but here to proof: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exchange {
    public static void main(String[] args){


        int howmany;
        int totalAmount;
        int[] arrayForId;
        int[] arrayForSales;

        Scanner inputData = new Scanner(System.in);

        totalAmount = 0;


        System.out.print("Please enter the number of salespeople to be processed: ");
        howmany = inputData.nextInt();

        arrayForId = new int[howmany];
        arrayForSales = new int[howmany];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayForId.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter an ID number and Sales Amount seperated by a space: ");        
            arrayForId[i] = inputData.nextInt();
            arrayForSales[i] = inputData.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tWeekly Sales by Salesperson");

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayForId.length ; i++){

            System.out.println("Id: " + arrayForId[i] + "\t Amount: " + arrayForSales[i]);
            totalAmount += arrayForSales[i];
        }

        System.out.println("\nTotal Sales: " + totalAmount);
        inputData.close();
}
```

}

hope this will help you.

Comment: of course this will only works if you input an integer, you can change the variable type from int to float or double, and then it will works better for floating point numbers